# How to add a script to a buildout project?

Tags: python, scripting, buildout

I have **setup.py** in a buildout project:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='',
  version='1.0',
  author='Denis Kolodin',
  author_email='...',
  url='...',
  scripts = ['scripts/myscript.py'], # The script I want to add to 'bin/' dir
)
```

Why buildout don't add that script to 'bin/'?
Can I develop scripts (not eggs) with buildout?

My **buildout.cfg**:

```
[buildout]
develop = .
parts = python scripts

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = marketwizard > 0.2.0
       jinja2

[scripts]
recipe = z3c.recipe.scripts
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, this is a buildout limitation: it does not understand the "script=" from your setup.py.  It *does* understand the "console_scripts=" so-called "entry point" from setuptools.  Google for it or look at an existing project that has it.

I've got a fix for buildout to make it support "scripts=", but that hasn't been accepted for inclusion yet.

Comment: The solution is quite suitable. Thank you!

Comment: Example at: http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2008/01/setuptools_tip_script_creation.html

Comment: Is it currently possible to do this with distutils?

Comment: Epeli: your question doesn't make much sense. Distutils will "just" create the script in the default python executable location: 'script' is a distutils config parameter, after all. So... What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I just make a real example.

Example setup.py

```
setup(name='',
  version='1.0',
  author='Denis Kolodin',
  author_email='...',
  url='...',
  entry_points={
    "console_scripts": [
        'myscript = scripts.myscript:main_function',
    ]
  }
)
```

Example buildout.cfg

```
[buildout]
develop = .
parts = python scripts

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = marketwizard > 0.2.0
   jinja2

[scripts]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
# to be available in your script
eggs = ${python:eggs}
scripts = myscript
```

Note: `main_function` this is function name (could any name) from your script module.